# Error con Three.js: Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: t is undefined

Tags: javascript, three.js

Tras configurar Three.js, con el archivo app.js, la consola me devuelve el siguiente error:
¿Qué sucede? ¿Qué significa este error?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Archivo app.js

```
//Variables for setup

let container;
let camera;
let renderer;
let scene;
let house;

function init(){
    container = document.querySelector('.scene');

    //Create a escene
    scene = new THREE.Scene();

    const fov = 35;
    const aspect = container.clientWidth / container.clientHeight;
    const near = 0.1;
    const far = 500;

    //Camera setup
    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(fov,aspect,near,far);
    camera.position.set(0, 0, 20);

    //Renderer
    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({antialias:true, alpha:true});
    renderer.setSize(container.clientWidth, container.clientHeight);
    renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);

    container.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

    //Load model
    let loader= new THREE.GLTFLoader();
    loader.load('/media/3d/paisaje/scene.gltf', function(gltf){
        scene.add(gltf.scene);
        renderer.render(scene.camera);
    });

}

init()
```

Comment: ¿Cual es la linea 40 en app.js?

Answer (score 0):

Cambia:

```
renderer.render(scene.camera);
```

por:

```
animate();
```

y crea la función animate fuera de init:

```
function animate() {
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
```